# proving that this function does not define a norm on $\mathbb R^2$ since the convexity

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

This problema use the previous part to conclude something, so I write all the parts.

First I have to prove that every norm in $\mathbb R^n$ is a convex function, I did it, it only requires the triangular inequality.

Then I have to prove that the set $$
S = \left\{ {\left( {x,y} \right) \in \mathbb R^2 :\sqrt {\left| x \right|}  + \sqrt {\left| y \right|}  < 1} \right\}
$$ is not convex.

I did it because $(0,\frac{1}{4}),(\frac{1}{4},0)\in S $ but $\frac{1}{2}(0,\frac{1}{4})+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{4},0)=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ not.

And then the book says, that using this I have to conclude that the function $$
\left| {\left| {\left( {x,y} \right)} \right|} \right| = \left( {\sqrt {\left| x \right|}  + \sqrt {\left| y \right|} } \right)^2 
$$ is not a norm on $\mathbb R^2$ 
But I don't know how to use that to prove the final part. Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is a convex function, then $S = \left\{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid f(x) < 1 \right\}$ is convex, and a norm is convex. So if $\|-\|$ were a norm, $S = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \|(x,y)\| < 1 \}$ would be convex, which isn't true, so $\|-\|$ is not a norm.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Prove that the unit ball is convex subset of $\mathbb R^n$ *(using that the norm function is convex)* then find a counterexample for the given function.